# /var/log/btmp not readable format?

Tags: ubuntu, log-files

Systemlogviewer in Ubuntu states that btmp is no usual file that can be opened. I don't know what happened. Some hours ago this problem hasn't yet occured? how can i fix it. when i delete btmp file. is there automatically created a new one? I'm a very newbie with logging and internals in ubuntu and linux. Please advice me step by step what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`last`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last) to read the binary file with the `-f` flag.  btmp logs failed authentication attempts.

Comment: ok, but how do i get rid of the notification in ubuntus log file viewer, some time ago this error didn't popup?

Comment: Seems to be a confirmed bug for a longer time now in Gnome Utils http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1458975